# How I should get resolution size icons for all devices

Tags: android, ios, icons, photoshop, resolution

Sorry for my bad english.
I need know about how all resolution size icons for all devices android and ios . 
by pexel, thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android icons require five separate sizes for different screen pixel densities. Icons for lower resolution are created automatically from the baseline.

1. mdpi (Baseline):   160 dpi
2. hdpi:              240 dpi
3. xhdpi:             320 dpi
4. xxhdpi:            480 dpi
5. xxxhdpi:           640 dpi

**Reference :**
http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/